# Execute Slim application middleware before route middleware

Tags: php, slim

According to the documentation http://www.slimframework.com/docs/concepts/middleware.html:

> The last middleware layer added is the first to be executed.

According to the same documentation, Slim supports `application`, `route`, and `group` middleware.

I wish to utilize both application and route middleware.  The application middleware is for authentication, and should be executed first.

How is this accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

Slim FW allows you to run route before middleware. According to this [link](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/application.html#application-configuration), you have to set config/setting `determineRouteBeforeAppMiddleware` to `true`.

Here is example code:

```html
<?php

$config = [
    'settings' => [
        'determineRouteBeforeAppMiddleware' => true,
    ],
];
$app = new \Slim\App($config);
```

Comment: Thank you tirta keniten.  Wouldn't have guessed that!  Let me do a bit of testing...

Comment: You are very welcome.
I suggest you to use a Slim Skeleton, so you don't need to built from scratch. There are so many Slim Skeleton on github. for example: [this](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Skeleton) and [this](https://github.com/akrabat/slim3-skeleton).